# How to return to original position using jQueryRotate

Tags: jquery, rotation

I'm trying out jQueryRotate, and I want to make a certain `img` rotate 90-degrees on clicking, then rotate back to the original position on the next click. I've looked relentlessly through different google searches, etc., but haven't found the answer I'm wanting.

Here's my code:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#menu_icon").rotate({bind:{click: function(){
                $(this).rotate({ duration:100, angle:0,animateTo:90,easing: $.easing.easeInOutExpo }, 10)}
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

How would I adjust this to create my desired result?
And I don't want it to just flash and go back 90-degrees,
I want it to move with animation like the first time clicking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#menu_icon").rotate({
    bind:{
        click: function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            if($this.data('rotate')){
                $this.data('rotate', false);
                $this.rotate({ duration:100, angle:0,animateTo:"-=90",easing: $.easing.easeInOutExpo }, 10) 
            }else{
                $this.data('rotate', true);
                $this.rotate({ duration:100, angle:0,animateTo:90,easing: $.easing.easeInOutExpo }, 10) 
            }

        }
    }
});
```

We simply add a data parameter that holds true/false, check with the conditional, and respond accordingly.

To go back 90 degrees from the last rotation, we simply employ `-=90` to the `animateTo` parameter.

[You can check it out for yourself](http://jsfiddle.net/pYhJ5/)